# Why does Fabric tell me that I have the wrong version installed?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

This is what it says in the console

```
[13:53:46] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/GameProvider) Loading Minecraft 1.19 with Fabric Loader 0.14.9
[13:53:46] [main/WARN] (FabricLoader/Resolution) Mod resolution failed
[13:53:46] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Resolution) Immediate reason: [HARD_DEP_NO_CANDIDATE example 1.0.0 {depends fabric-api @ [*]}, ROOT_FORCELOAD_SINGLE example 1.0.0]
[13:53:46] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Resolution) Reason: [HARD_DEP example 1.0.0 {depends fabric-api @ [*]}]
[13:53:46] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Resolution) Fix: add [add:fabric-api 1 ([(-∞,∞)])], remove [], replace []
[13:53:46] [main/ERROR] (FabricLoader) Incompatible mod set!
 net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FormattedException: Mod resolution encountered an incompatible mod set!
A potential solution has been determined:
     - Install fabric-api, any version.
Unmet dependency listing:
     - Mod 'Example Mod' (example) 1.0.0 requires any version of fabric-api, which is missing!
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FabricLoaderImpl.load(FabricLoaderImpl.java:190) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.9.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:148) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.9.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:68) [fabric-loader-0.14.9.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23) [fabric-loader-0.14.9.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) [dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

when I try to run it as a minecraft client, a fabric-api window opens with this error message

```
Incompatible mod set!
net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FormattedException: Mod resolution encountered an incompatible mod set!
A potential solution has been determined:
     - Install fabric-api, any version.
Unmet dependency listing:
     - Mod 'Example Mod' (example) 1.0.0 requires any version of fabric-api, which is missing!
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FabricLoaderImpl.load(FabricLoaderImpl.java:190)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:148)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:68)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

I have installed the right version of fabric-api after I got that error, and I re-opened the project and tried it again but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

As logs said, you need the [Fabric API](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/fabric-api) in any version.

This requirement is made by your plugin, in your `fabric.mod.json` file.